# How to move the block under the sidebar in the payment step of checkout

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, sidebar

I have a block that I display on the checkout at the bottom of the page

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout_attention_block" after="main.content" template="Magento_Checkout::checkout-attention.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

How to add this block under the sidebar block

```
<aside role="dialog" class="modal-custom opc-sidebar opc-summary-wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="checkout.sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_sidebar_block" after="opc-sidebar" template="Vendor_Module::custom-sidebar.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create a file named checkout_index_index.xml inside the view/frontend/layout